# Full path in Android Studio tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I noticed that that some of tabs in android studio displays the full path to the file layout. as "**res/.../layoutname.xml**". I have learned that it occurs if the files are available in several configurations, but I have no alternative layouts. How to solve this? 
*What i already done:*

1. Clean project (Build->Clean Project)
2. Ivalidate Caches and  Restart (File-> Ivalidate Caches / Restart)
3. Search everywhere (Double Shift) and type "layoutname" found layout with same name with path "../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layou/" (i think here my issue) and only for this layout, but in project i have more than 10 layouts

Comment: You cannot edit `app/build` files. Those are auto-generated.

Comment: @cricket_007, i know that, but why android studio show in tabs full path to file ? but no one file was overriden

Comment: Not sure. Could be an IDE setting

Comment: Android Studio seems to show the full path when 2+ tabs are open on files with the same basename. That does not necessarily mean that they are equivalent files in separate resource sets.